PowerShell, WPF, DataGrid: Image will not display?
I'm trying to use PowerShell and WPF to write a Datagrid with an image column.  But I can't get the image to display for the life of me.
I need to display an image "in memory" as opposed to a physical image on disk.  Hence i try and convert it in this example:
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase

# Function to convert image file to BitmapSource
function Convert-ImageFileToBitmapSource {
    param (
        [string] $ImagePath
    )

    # Load the image from file
    $bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($ImagePath)

    # Convert Bitmap to BitmapSource
    $bitmapStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    $bitmap.Save($bitmapStream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)

    $bitmapSource = New-Object System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
    $bitmapSource.BeginInit()
    $bitmapSource.StreamSource = $bitmapStream
    $bitmapSource.EndInit()

    # Dispose of the original Bitmap to free resources
    $bitmap.Dispose()

    return $bitmapSource
}

# Create a DataTable with columns
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", [System.String])
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Icon", [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource])

# Load image from file and add to DataTable
$imagePath = "C:\Example\Icon.png"
$iconBitmapSource = Convert-ImageFileToBitmapSource -ImagePath $imagePath

# Add rows to DataTable
$row1 = $dataTable.NewRow()
$row1["Name"] = "Icon"
$row1["Icon"] = $iconBitmapSource
$dataTable.Rows.Add($row1)

# Create WPF XAML content
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Image in DataGrid Example" Height="400" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icon">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="32" Height="32" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

# Load XAML content
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

# Set DataContext to DataTable
$window.DataContext = $dataTable.DefaultView

# Show the window
$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null


Why are you using an intermediate System.Drawing.Bitmap? You can directly create a BitmapImage from a FileStream.

In reality, I'm reading/extracting icons from exe's but i didnt want to convolute the example.  The point being, I just can't get an image in memory to display in the WPF datagrid....

When setting the StreamSource property to a Stream that is disposed before the BitmapImage is shown, you must set BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad. You should generally also rewind the Stream before assigning it to StreamSource.
